# How to add ArrayList into SharedPreference and display it?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have an ArrayList in a different Activity so I used Shared Preference to get it.

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("ShoppingListFile", Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    itemList.size();
    String json = gson.toJson(itemList);
    editor.putString("KEY_ArrayList", json);
    editor.apply();
```

After I retrieved the data by

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("ShoppingListFile", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String json = prefs.getString("KEY_ArrayList", null);
    Type type = new TypeToken<ArrayList<Model>>() {}.getType();
    ArrayList<Model> arrayList = gson.fromJson(json, type);
```

And last of all I included it in my Adapter

```
mRecyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view1);
        mAdapter1 = new RecyclerViewAdapter(arrayList);
        LinearLayoutManager manager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity(), LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(manager);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter1);
```

My problem is that it doesn't show any items in my recyclerview.

Comment: Make sure, size is what `arrayList` ? at first

Comment: I've added it to the code but it still would not show

Comment: Did you try setting breakpoint at the line where you are reading shared prefs and check whether you have a problem with storing data or parsing json?

Comment: i think what @IntelliJAmiya meant was to print the size of the list to make sure things exist in it. If the size is 0, well, then, thats why nothing is saved. :)